# Sending ERC20 tokens using the transfer function

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, bsc

I'm pretty new to programing in solidity and I'm currently trying to run a simple smart contract in Remix, seen bellow:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract Swap  {
    address public owner;
    uint256 public balance;
    
    event TransferReceived(address _from, uint _amount);
    event TransferSent(address _from, address _destAddr, uint _amount);
    
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    receive() payable external {
        balance += msg.value;
        emit TransferReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }    
    
    function withdraw(uint amount, address payable destAddr) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can withdraw funds"); 
        require(amount <= balance, "Insufficient funds");
        
        destAddr.transfer(amount);
        balance -= amount;
        emit TransferSent(msg.sender, destAddr, amount);
    }
    
    function transferERC20(IERC20 token, address to, uint256 amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can withdraw funds"); 
        uint256 erc20balance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(amount <= erc20balance, "balance is low");
        token.transfer(to, amount);
        emit TransferSent(msg.sender, to, amount);
    }    
}
```

While I can successfully send BNB and call the `withdraw` function giving the value sent and my wallet address in the BSC testnet, I'm having issues when running the `transferERC20` function. The only output that I get when calling this method is the following message:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
> transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution
> reverted" }

I've tried several different addresses that I found in the testnet.bscscan website for BNB while making sure that the contract had enough funds for transfering, but I had no success.

Can someone suggest what might be going wrong in my contract/setup? Am I making this transfer properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- fix constrcutor

  ```
  constructor() {
        // payable allows payment of ether with a call.
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
  ```
- make sure those `require` statements are satisfied

  ```
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can withdraw funds"); 
    require(amount <= balance, "Insufficient funds");
  ```
- check that you are connected to correct network

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It really was an issue with the address and balance of the contract.